# Markov model where probabilities are variable?

Tags: markov-process

I'm training a markov model where the transition probabilities are predicted by another model.

Is there a term for this type of markov model? Below we have a markov model with two nodes:

```
O - > O 
   -> o
```

The transition probability is defined by an external model `f(node1, node2) = p`. Is this is done often? I found that I was in a situation to do this.

Comment: I don't think there's anything in Markov model that says that probabilities must be constant as long as they have finite memory

Comment: I was wondering if this is common or not. I just hope that I'm not re-inventing the wheel.